# Extract at a certain command several lines

Tags: command-line, line, extract

I found (of course) lots of threads about extracting lines from a file, but I couldn't transfer it to my problem. Given a file with a structure like this:

```
Time = 0.1
bla bla
Time = 0.2
bla bla

**StartExtractionPart1Here**
data i want
in file 1
svereal lines of code
**endExtractionPart1**

**StartExtractionPart2Here**
data i want
in file 2
severeal lines of code
**endExtractionPart2**

Time = 0.3

bla bla
```

so Pseudo-Code would be:

```
find a given time
    find a given startflag
        write all files into file 1 until endflag is reached
    do that for all Parts
```

I can change the Syntax of the start- and endflags as I need them. The "Extraction Parts" are printed in every timestep but I just want those of a given time.

Comment: Depends on what platform and command interpreter you are using

Comment: hi Jay
Unix system and I would use "any" command interpreter.. I started with awk, but did not suceed